# Auto-redirect to new Wordpress Site URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My blog was earlier hosted at prasadgupte.com/go since the old provider would not allow modifying htaccess in the root dir. Now, I wish to move the blog to prasadgupte.com/blog

Since the blog is over a couple of years old & has lot of posts, I would like all hits to prasadgupte.com/go/something to go to prasadgupte.com/blog/something

Can someone help me with the HTACCESS inside the "go" dir to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (this will go in .htaccess in your `/go` folder):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

This should use a permanent redirect any access to /go/ to the exact same place in /blog/